# How can i check all the checkboxes, even the ones hidden by pagination?

Tags: java, checkbox, pagination, zk

I have an array of informations that will be shown in a table justr like the image:

[image: exemple 1]

As you can see, there is this checkbox that checks all the other ones. The first pagination only shows the 10 firsts results of 26. To check the checkboxes i am calling OnCreate of each checkbox and adding it in a list so a can check everyone, but the OnCreate of each checkbox is only called when i go through the pages; if i dont, only the 10 firsts are added in array.

I cannot send it checked when sending the informations because the checkboxes are not created yet.

Does anyone knows how can i add every checkbox of each line in that array?

obs: I am using zk 7.0.0

Some code:

```
<column label="2ª Via" align="center" >
    <checkbox id="chkbxPai" onCheck="eac808$composer.habilitaTodosCheckBox(self.checked)"/>
```

```
<cell align="center">
    <checkbox id="chkbox2Via" onCreate="eac808$composer.adicionaNaListDeCheckBox(self)" />
```

```
public void adicionaNaListDeCheckBox(Checkbox checkbox) {
    if (!this.listaDeCheckbox.contains(checkbox)) {
       this.listaDeCheckbox.add(checkbox);
   }
}
```

Comment: the ones "hidden by pagination" aren't currently there

Comment: yes, so can can i get them?

Comment: no. at that point, they don't exist, that's the whole thing about pagination

Comment: You don't need to get them. Why don't you save the state of your checkbox `select all`? Let's say the state can be false and true (all boxes must be selected). Then when you go to different page and new checkboxes are being created, you check the state of 'select all'. If it's true, set checkboxes to be selected whilst they are being created.

Comment: @CrazySabbath hi. 'cus when i do that, i resolve the problem in backend, but when i go to other page and the checkboxes starts to exist, they are not checked. I have to keep on verifying this and changing the status of that checkbox 'select all' everytime... i was looking for a better way to do that :/

Comment: @Aimée No you don't resolve this in backend if going to other page loses the state of `select all`

Comment: @Aimée your current solution wouldn't work even if you switch through all pages. As soon as you leave a page, the checkboxes there are "destroyed", so the ones you have in your `listaDeCheckbox` might not even exist anymore. Even if you back to the page, there will be **new** checkboxes, not the old ones in your list. Could you follow Hawk's idea and use multiple selection with `setCheckmark(true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you have checked the backend data. I think you don't render those checkboxes based on your backend data, so that when you go to the next page, Grid still renders unchecked checkbox. So check your Grid renderer code (or template) or post it in your question.

One solution is to use [ListModelList](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.3/zk/org/zkoss/zul/ListModelList.html) and [Listbox](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Listbox) which supports the selection.(`Grid` doesn't support the selection).

```
ListModel listModelList; //contains some items
listModelList.setMultiple(true);

//select all
listModelList.setSelection(listModelList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i didn't found a better solution and my backend data was already checked, I've solved this problem by verifying everytime the user goes to another page, so i could check the new created checkboxes. Thanks everyone for the help!